# Construct partial object and infer types correctly

Tags: typescript

I have an object A and I want to create a new object B that contains some of the fields of object A. It's a pretty straightforward task however I still cannot figure out how to type it correctly. It's better to explain it with code:

```
interface Data {
    userName: string
    photoUrl: string
    age: number
}

const data: Data = {
    userName: 'John',
    photoUrl: 'https://...',
    age: 100
}


// new data can look like for example {userName: 'John'}
const newData: Partial<Data> = {}


// 1. solution - doesn't work because key is of type string
for (const key in data) {
    /* if (//some complex condition ) */
    newData[key] = data[key]
}


// 2. solution - keys are typed correctly but still doesn't work properly
const keys = Object.keys(data)  as Array<keyof typeof data>
keys.forEach(key => {
    /* if (//some complex condition ) */
    newData[key] = data[key]
})


// Anything else I am missing? :)
```

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=33&ssc=34&pln=1&pc=1#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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to iterate over narrowly typed object keys (type `keyof T` rather than `string`) of an object. [Here's a great article](https://effectivetypescript.com/2020/05/26/iterate-objects/) that explores some approaches to this TS problem.

A few solutions:

1. Use `Object.entries` and assert the key's type:

```
for (const [str, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    const key = str as keyof typeof data;
    //    ^^^ : keyof Data
    newData[key] = value;
    //             ^^^^^ : any
}
```

2. Narrow the type of your key variable by declaring it outside the `for` statement:

```
// This one is similar to casting the result of `Object.keys`, but a bit less verbose.  
let key: keyof Data;
for (key in data) {
    newData[key] = data[key] as any;
}
```

Note: if your object has more than one property type, you have to cast the value to `any` to make it work on an assignment, or you will get an error like *`Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.`*. In your example, given `key` with type `keyof Data`, TSC can infer that the value of `data[key]` is either a `number` or a `string`. However, it cannot infer which key is being referenced during a given iteration of `for (key in data)`, which means it cannot determine if the value of `data[key]` is the same type as `newData[key]`. If `age` was a `string` (so that every property was a `string` type), it would work as expected.

For example:

```
interface I1 {
  a: string
  b: number
}

interface I2 {
  a: string
  b: string
}

const i1: I1 = { a: 'a', b: 0 }
let key: keyof I1;
for(key in i1) {
  i1[key] = i1[key]; 
//^^^^^^^ Error: is this a number or a string? And which do I need?
}

const i2: I2 = { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
let key2: keyof I2;
for(key2 in i1) {
  i2[key2] = i2[key2]; // Ok: I am getting a string and I need a string.
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUASAFcBnaAOTgFsIAuZYsKUAcwIAcALAezC4FUoAGzoMmIVvjjNayEIUoAjaLgC+uXAi4gGyACYY4ddJmQBeHARLkqMgOQApLhxC2ANO268Bw5LY5gwNmIaAHoQgDpItwIpGQBGAAYE1Q0tHRAIAHdjQ2QABTgoMGA4QQAeHIA+Mxw1XDDkOPDkEhZkAHkFACsIBDBwiHAmCGJkOBBdZDAATzYUOGJSIuAtcNwYLihkAApNbTBkAG1RV2QAN1LCCABdZC4YDu7e-sHGYBHt-UwASm+LfD2OgA1hBpjVRGNRiDpvcprMILCvnAANwEDLZAyHaG3cwXQRXVF1eohZAAJmaxC4+OKWmQAFpkNDRoUUDM5pNNFAoM9BGCFIQDgxgIJBHouCMXAdMpsgcg2FAuHMhNNcIIIAdoXRobCcqiNltttDkKA9AY-nh8OicljQTjTZgbdNbgsxiBpoT1A0AKJczZ0AAq8N8ojaAB9ZPIlFBbMbRiAeJDiMBmCA4Ao1VMuHC5r5CBMIDBQBBdLY1vqdkaTUjzWistbsTUkY7rh7PSSFFoSMgIAAPKhsNW4C2gSCwRAoACScX+uRD4gICjockUynwdXwI+g8CQyAnpJnIje8-wi-oR4k68BB2AcToU5q2DGdFscDcyFPCWQanwao1oK1oKwlOqL4PqhqgsaIDGnENb4BucTNjUN7NsiyDer6UB0MAoxgBw2FjBGK5bJsBFzswAD8yAAIITMgmR4QgHBirusgQMW5EEJeaTXqSd77uYj65C+b6nrYCgxt+v6MqCvHSTCDx7iBYHQvuJo3rBwCko6pJ2pp2ktmhJLtECd5jJQyDSAEbRYGRrqTBOrHFqR55rGuqhAA)